# Any way to simplify R code?

Tags: r

I have the following code but it seems very long winded - as I'm doing the same thing to each file I figured there must be a method to simplify but it alludes me at present! Any help appreciated as always:

```
.LVB.SF.1.1 <- read.csv("LVB_SF_1-1.csv", header=T, sep=","); .LVB.SF.1.6 <- read.csv("LVB_SF_1-6.csv", header=T, sep=",")
.LVB.SF.1.2 <- read.csv("LVB_SF_1-2.csv", header=T, sep=","); .LVB.SF.1.7 <- read.csv("LVB_SF_1-7.csv", header=T, sep=",")
.LVB.SF.1.3 <- read.csv("LVB_SF_1-3.csv", header=T, sep=","); .LVB.SF.1.8 <- read.csv("LVB_SF_1-8.csv", header=T, sep=",")
.LVB.SF.1.4 <- read.csv("LVB_SF_1-4.csv", header=T, sep=","); .LVB.SF.1.9 <- read.csv("LVB_SF_1-9.csv", header=T, sep=",")
.LVB.SF.1.5 <- read.csv("LVB_SF_1-5.csv", header=T, sep=","); .LVB.SF.2.0 <- read.csv("LVB_SF_2.csv", header=T, sep=",")

# Interpolate the missing monthly values - linear interpolation of above
x <- zoo(.LVB.SF.1.1); .LVB.SF.1.1 <- as.data.frame(na.approx(x)); x <- zoo(.LVB.SF.1.2); .LVB.SF.1.2 <- as.data.frame(na.approx(x))
x <- zoo(.LVB.SF.1.3); .LVB.SF.1.3 <- as.data.frame(na.approx(x)); x <- zoo(.LVB.SF.1.4); .LVB.SF.1.4 <- as.data.frame(na.approx(x))
x <- zoo(.LVB.SF.1.5); .LVB.SF.1.5 <- as.data.frame(na.approx(x)); x <- zoo(.LVB.SF.1.6); .LVB.SF.1.6 <- as.data.frame(na.approx(x))
x <- zoo(.LVB.SF.1.7); .LVB.SF.1.7 <- as.data.frame(na.approx(x)); x <- zoo(.LVB.SF.1.8); .LVB.SF.1.8 <- as.data.frame(na.approx(x))
x <- zoo(.LVB.SF.1.9); .LVB.SF.1.9 <- as.data.frame(na.approx(x)); x <- zoo(.LVB.SF.2.0); .LVB.SF.2.0 <- as.data.frame(na.approx(x))

# Create rowmeans columns for all the above
.LVB.SF.1.1$Mean <- rowMeans(.LVB.SF.1.1[,c(2:4)]); .LVB.SF.1.6$Mean <- rowMeans(.LVB.SF.1.6[,c(2:4)])
.LVB.SF.1.2$Mean <- rowMeans(.LVB.SF.1.2[,c(2:4)]); .LVB.SF.1.7$Mean <- rowMeans(.LVB.SF.1.7[,c(2:4)])
.LVB.SF.1.3$Mean <- rowMeans(.LVB.SF.1.3[,c(2:4)]); .LVB.SF.1.8$Mean <- rowMeans(.LVB.SF.1.8[,c(2:4)])
.LVB.SF.1.4$Mean <- rowMeans(.LVB.SF.1.4[,c(2:4)]); .LVB.SF.1.9$Mean <- rowMeans(.LVB.SF.1.9[,c(2:4)])
.LVB.SF.1.5$Mean <- rowMeans(.LVB.SF.1.5[,c(2:4)]); .LVB.SF.2.0$Mean <- rowMeans(.LVB.SF.2.0[,c(2:4)])

# RMSE Calculation
LVB.RMSE.TWS.1.1 <- rmse(LVB.OBS.TWS.LAG_ONLY[,1], .LVB.SF.1.1[,5]); LVB.RMSE.TWS.1.6 <- rmse(LVB.OBS.TWS.LAG_ONLY[,1], .LVB.SF.1.6[,5])
LVB.RMSE.TWS.1.2 <- rmse(LVB.OBS.TWS.LAG_ONLY[,1], .LVB.SF.1.2[,5]); LVB.RMSE.TWS.1.7 <- rmse(LVB.OBS.TWS.LAG_ONLY[,1], .LVB.SF.1.7[,5])
LVB.RMSE.TWS.1.3 <- rmse(LVB.OBS.TWS.LAG_ONLY[,1], .LVB.SF.1.3[,5]); LVB.RMSE.TWS.1.8 <- rmse(LVB.OBS.TWS.LAG_ONLY[,1], .LVB.SF.1.8[,5])
LVB.RMSE.TWS.1.4 <- rmse(LVB.OBS.TWS.LAG_ONLY[,1], .LVB.SF.1.4[,5]); LVB.RMSE.TWS.1.9 <- rmse(LVB.OBS.TWS.LAG_ONLY[,1], .LVB.SF.1.9[,5])
LVB.RMSE.TWS.1.5 <- rmse(LVB.OBS.TWS.LAG_ONLY[,1], .LVB.SF.1.5[,5]); LVB.RMSE.TWS.2.0 <- rmse(LVB.OBS.TWS.LAG_ONLY[,1], .LVB.SF.2.0[,5])
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try a loop, perhaps?

Comment: You can read all the files in to a list and then do all the operations within the list. i.e. `files <- list.files(pattern='LVB_SF_.*.csv'); lst <- lapply(files, read.table, header=TRUE, sep=","); lapply(lst, function(x) zoo(..))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When performing same same sequence of actions multiple times, **function composition** should help a lot. For example

```
interpolate <- function(x) as.data.frame(na.approx(zoo(x)))

# take data.frame and add 'Mean' column containing mean of columns 2:4
addRowmeans <- function(x) {
    x$Mean <- rowMeans(x[ , 2:4])
    x
}
```

Using these will make your code less bulky, as shown in the end.

As for iterating through data sets to perform above actions, you could use a list of data.frames structure and go through it using a **for loop**. This reduces code copying and pasting and make your script more flexible, as changing number of files won't require much manual work.

A much better idea than for loops is to use **apply** family of functions as in R they are faster and have more comprehensible syntax.

With functions defined above and `lapply` from base R, algorithm from OP reduces to

```
# read all files, store them as list of data.frames
lapply(files, read.csv, h = TRUE) -> data.list

# Interpolate the missing monthly values - linear interpolation of above
lapply(data.list, interpolate) -> data.interpolated

# Create rowmeans columns for all the above
lapply(data.interpolated , addRowmeans) -> data.interpolated

# RMSE Calculation     (assuming rmse has arguments names x and y)
lapply(data.interpolated[5], function(x) rmse(LVB.OBS.TWS.LAG_ONLY[1], x))
```

Where files were created as below

```
sprintf('%1.1f', seq(from = 1.9, to = 2.1, by = .1)) -> nums
files <- paste('prefix_', nums, '.csv', sep = '')

files
[1] "prefix_1.9.csv" "prefix_2.0.csv" "prefix_2.1.csv"
```